# GCP Datastore vs Search API performance benchmarks?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gae-search

Are there any existing benchmarks about GCP Datastore queries and Search queries performance?

I'm interested how the performance changes as the data grows. For instance, if we have:

```
class Project:
  members = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

and we have document in Search like:

```
SearchDocument([AtomField(name=member, value='value...'), ...])
```

I want to run a search to get all project ids the user is member of. Something like:

```
ndb.query(keys_only=True).filter(Project.members == 'This Member')
```

in Datastore and similar query in the Search.

How would the performance compare when there are 10, 100, ... 16 * 6 objects?

I'm interested whether there is some rule of thumb about the latency we could expect for this simple kind of queries. Of course I can go and try that, but would like to get some intuitive idea about the performance I can expect beforehand, if someone had done similar benchmarks. Also, I would like to avoid spending $ and time on writing/reading data I would later need to delete, so if someone could share their experience, that would be much appreciated!

p.s. I use Python, but would assume the answer would be same/similar for all languages which have support for GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Until this moment, Api Search is only supported for [Python 2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search), unfortunately this version of Python is no longer supported, so you should consider that you will not be able to receive support for this service.

On the other hand, take a look at the [code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/4925#issuecomment-368938736) provided in this thread, it can give you an idea of how to perform a benchmark test for Datastore using python 3.